# Cannot ping windows server instance from redhat instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

Running into an issue pinging from RedHat instance to a windows server instance. I have tried multiple things within the security settings with absolutely no luck. I can ping the RedHat instance from the Windows Server but I can not ping from the RedHat instance to the Windows instance.

- Updated the Security Groups for both instances to allow all ICMP traffic on Ipv4 and 6.
- Tried custom rule for ICMP to allow all traffic.

Looked at a few other questions on here also that are similar with no result. 
- AWS EC2 instance not responding to ping (Petr Mensik)
- AWS EC2 instance cannot ping certain address (Petr Mensik)

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are able to ping using IP address and not with hostname then you can try this option. https://devopsdiaryblog.wordpress.com/2017/11/06/resolve-ping-issue-with-hostname-linux/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding security group is enough to connect the instances.In security group did you  allow the ICMP Protocol to be accessible from all subnets.

[Security Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEyA9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Windows firewall, I've found it generally drops ICMP unless you configured it to accept ICMP / ping requests.

Following that, security groups and NACLs are the next most likely suspects.